# Find the equations of the lines tangent to $r=4\sin(3\theta)$ at the pole.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates, tangent-line

> Find the equations of the lines tangent to $r=4\sin(3\theta)$ at the pole.

Firstly I used the facts that $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ and took their derivatives to get $dx/d\theta$ and $dy/d\theta$ so that I could get $dy/dx$. Since everything is in $\theta$, I try to find the $\theta$s that put a point at the pole (so basically, find the thetas that satisfy $4\sin (3\theta) = 0$), which are $0,\pi,2\pi,...$ However, when I do plug that into $dy/dx$, the numerator cancels to $0$ because of the sines, and it seems like I only have a horizontal tangent. Is that right though?

Comment: [no](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3D4*sin(3*theta))

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Thanks for reminding me — I had quite forgotten about this post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r=0$ at $\theta=0$, $\theta=\pi/3$, $\theta=2\pi/3$.

The cartesian equations are
$$x=4\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
$$y=4\sin(3\theta)\sin(\theta)$$
Taking the derivative
$$x'=12\cos(3\theta)\cos(\theta) - 4\sin(3\theta)\sin(\theta)$$
$$y'=12\cos(3\theta)\sin(\theta) + 4\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
At $\theta=0$:
$$x'=12$$
$$y'=0$$
so you have a horizontal line (tangent vector (1,0))

At $\theta=\pi/3$:
$$x'=-12\cos(\pi/3)=-6$$
$$y'=-12\sin(\pi/3)=-6\sqrt{3}$$
so you have another line with tangent vector (1,$\sqrt{3}$)

Repeat for $\theta=2\pi/3$...

Answer (score 0):

HINT...the tangents at the origin are the values of $\theta$ for which $r\rightarrow0$, so you need to solve $r=0$ to find them